# Use a variable in javascript function inside Java code

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a javascript function as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener ("message", OnMessage, false);
    function OnMessage (event) {
        var test = event.data;
        <%
             ReadCookiesServlet readCookiesServlet=new ReadCookiesServlet();
             readCookiesServlet.doGet(<%=test%>,response);
       %>
    }
</script>
```

What I actually needs is to pass the value of event.data to the method doGet.How can I pass this value?

Thanks.

Comment: i guess the only way you have is to make a HTTP call to the doGet method....better if an AJAX call

Comment: `readCookiesServlet.doGet(<%=test%>,response);` wtf dude? you shouldn't call `doPost` and `doGet` servlet methods yourself.

Comment: yep :) Just a sample code. What I need is to use javascript variable inside java code

Comment: So use ajax call. Something like jQuery's [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) will do the work.

Comment: Everv0id, Im just a newbie for ajax. Can you please help me to use ajax here

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

The problem with you approach is that  the java code is compiled before any javascript function is created so it doesnt know what `test` and will pass  `<%=test%>` as a string to function

Btw  `readCookiesServlet.doGet(<%=test%>,response);` will give you a compile time error because `test` is not defined in java code it is defined in javascript code and also for its type.

Comment: @Hasanthi if you find my answer helful consider accepting it

Comment: Can You please help me to write an ajax call for this

Comment: @Hasanthi yes ufcorse check the link in my answer if you find any trouble then let me know.